# Checking if an image of a certain type (png) exists in a directory in Python

Tags: python, directory

I'm wondering how can I check in a certain directory if it has a png image(it's name can be anything). If yes, then save the name of the images in a list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `glob` library and "`*`" as a wildcard e.g.

```py
import glob
pngs = glob.glob("yourdir/*.png") # len(pngs) == 0 means we have no matches
# ['image1.png', 'image2.png' ...]
```

See more examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Comment: Shouldn't it be pngs = glob.glob("mydir/*.png")?

Comment: @Burschken yes you're right, already fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple code:

```
import glob
targetPattern = r"C:\..\*.png"
glob.glob(targetPattern)
```

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.